# jmeter service script. restart not working

Tags: java, shell, service, centos, jmeter

I am attempting to use the following service script on Centos 6.6 for apache jmeter.

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# chkconfig:         2345 85 15
# Provides:          jmeter-server
# Required-Start:    $syslog $local_fs
# Required-Stop:     $syslog $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Apache JMeter Remote Server
# Description:       Apache JMeter Remote Server runs JMeter tests issued from a remote server.
### END INIT INFO

# Author: Brian Flad <bflad417 at gmail dot com>

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
NAME=jmeter
JMETER_PATH=/usr/share/jmeter
# RMI_HOST_DEF is referenced/used inside the $JMETER_PATH/bin/$NAME-server script
# Change this to your IP
export RMI_HOST_DEF="-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.0.2.15"
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
JAVA_PID=$(pgrep -f "[A]pacheJMeter.jar $RMI_HOST_DEF -Dserver_port=1099")

# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

# Source networking configuration.
. /etc/sysconfig/network

# Check that networking is up.
[ "${NETWORKING}" = "no" ] && exit 0

[ -f $JMETER_PATH/bin/$NAME-server ] || exit 0
[ -f $JMETER_PATH/bin/$NAME ] || exit 0

#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
        [ -n "$JAVA_PID" ] && echo "$NAME already started" && exit 0
        echo -n "Starting $NAME: "
        $JMETER_PATH/bin/$NAME-server 2>&1 &
        RETVAL=$?
        MODE="normal"
        echo "$NAME started in $MODE mode"
        [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/$NAME
}

#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop()
{
        [ -z "$JAVA_PID" ] && echo "$NAME already stopped" && exit 0
        echo -n "Shutting down $NAME: "
        kill "$JAVA_PID"
        RETVAL=$?
        echo "return is $RETVAL"
        echo
        [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/subsys/$NAME
}

#
# Function that gives status of daemon/server
#
do_status()
{
        if [ -n "$JAVA_PID" ]; then
            MODE="RUNNING pid $JAVA_PID"
            RETVAL=0
        else
            MODE="STOPPED"
            RETVAL=1
        fi
        echo "$NAME is $MODE"
}

#
# Function that stops and restarts daemon/server
#
do_restart()
{
        do_stop
        do_start
}

case "$1" in
  start)
        do_start
        ;;
  stop)
        do_stop
        ;;
  status)
        do_status
        ;;
  restart|force-reload)
        do_restart
        ;;
  condrestart)
        [ -e /var/lock/subsys/$NAME ] && do_restart
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart|force-reload}" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

service jmeter start and service jmeter stop are working fine but when I attempt to do service jmeter restart, it is stopping the java instance but it is not starting it again as it thinks that jmeter is already running.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not resetting/updating `JAVA_PID` between stop and start commands, so `start` would exit based on the following condition:

```
 [ -n "$JAVA_PID" ] && echo "$NAME already started" && exit 0
```

you need to either reset/update `JAVA_PID` after stopping it, e.g.

```
update_pid()
{
    JAVA_PID=$(pgrep -f "[A]pacheJMeter.jar $RMI_HOST_DEF -Dserver_port=1099")
}
...
do_restart()
{
     do_stop
     update_pid
     do_start
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That worked great. I found I also had to add a sleep command to the do_stop function after attempting to kill the process to allow time for it to be fully stopped.